# Javascriptをデバッグするときの、Dateの文字列化を変更できるか

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

#### 質問

Javascriptを、Chrome,EdgeやFirefoxの開発ツールとVSCodeを使ってデバッグを行っています。
デバッグ中に変数をウォッチすると変数は文字列化されて表示されますが、米国式(MDY)に表示されるのが読み取りづらいです。

**読み取りやすいYMDの並びで表示させる方法はありますか？**

#### 環境

Chrome 120.0.6099.217
VS Code 1.85.1

---

#### 試したこと

Dateオブジェクト自身で文字列化しているのか調べてみるために以下のことを試してみました。

```js
console.log(new Date(2023,1,15));
```

は、`Wed Feb 15 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (日本標準時)`と米国式の並びで表示されます。
これは

```javascript
new Date(2023,1,15).toString();
```

を実行した時と同じです。

toString()による文字列化が行われて表示されているのか調べるため、ためしに

```javascript
Date.prototype.toString = Date.prototype.toISOString;
console.log(new Date(2023,1,15));  // Wed Feb 15 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (日本標準時)
console.log(new Date(2023,1,15).toString()) ;// 2023-02-14T15:00:00.000Z
console.log(new Date(2023,1,15)[Symbol.toPrimitive]('string')); // Wed Feb 15 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (日本標準時)
```

してみると、toString()なしではやはり米国式の文字列になり、デバッガのウォッチでも米国式のままでした。
toDateString,toGMTStringの変更なども試しましたが、prototypeの定義では影響しないようです。

toStringの挙動についての仕様は[EMCAScript](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date.prototype.tostring)に書かれているのが見つかりましたが、to**Stringを使わない文字列化については見つけられませんでした。

---

#### その他

デバッグプロセスとデバッガが通信するのにJSONが使われているかもしれないと思い、toISOStringを細工してみましたが、JSON化は変更できてもデバッガのウォッチは変更されませんでした。

```javascript
Date.prototype.toISOString = Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString;
JSON.stringify( {"D": new Date(2023,1,15)}) // {"D":"0:00:00"}
```